# qmake on Windows: How to convert backslashes into forward slashes

Tags: windows, qmake

I am trying to use bison, so I've specified following line:

```
bison.commands = bison -d -o ${QMAKE_FILE_PATH}/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.parser.cc ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
```

The problem is that `${QMAKE_FILE_IN}` and `${QMAKE_FILE_PATH}` contain backslashes which bison doesn't understand.

So how to convert them into forward slashes?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`shell_path`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#shell-path-path) function:

```
bison.commands = bison -d -o \"$$shell_path(${QMAKE_FILE_PATH}/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.parser.cc)\" \"$$shell_path(${QMAKE_FILE_IN})\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Late but...

```
message($$replace(QMAKE_FILE_PATH, \\\\, /))
```

...replaces backslash (needs to be escaped twice, thus the quadruple backslash) by forward slashes.